# Вы выросли из разработчика в бизнесмена?

Tags: работа

Есть такой опыт, и если есть, то расскажите вашу success или fail историю :)

Comment: Не знаю, рост ли это.

Лично я и не пытался. Из моих знакомых действительно успешных переквалификаций (IT бизнес) нет. А так, на хлеб с маслом, есть несколько.

Comment: действительно, заработать на хлеб с маслом можно. из всех разработчиков, кого знаю, все стараются пойти куда ни будь в хорошую компанию сис админам, т.к. платят больше, и гораздо стабильнее.

Comment: Разработчики в сисадмины идут? Видимо плохие разработчики. (не в обиду сисадминам говорю, разумеется).

Comment: Таких примеров довольно-таки много, только вот загвоздка в том, что здесь в основном сидят действующие разработчики, поэтому рассказа о том, "как я стал бизнесменом" ждать вряд ли стоит

Comment: > Разработчики в сисадмины идут?

С каких пор базнесмен - это сисадмин?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня знакомы вырос. Это мой бывший работодатель. Окончил иняз, обучился САМ программированию. Напсал свою CMS - создал фирму и сейчас делает сайты (они из лучших в нашем городе).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется это не связанные понятия. Тут вопрос в том есть ли у Вас желание и ресурсы расти дальше под дядей, или самостоятельно. Обычно при достижении специалистом потолка роста, ему предлагают партнёрство, прекрасно понимаю что если ресурс ценный он уйдёт без этого сам. В России это правда не особо развито пока :-)

Comment: Знакомая ситуаций с одним знакомым, правдо партнерство под вопросом )

Comment: @Чад, а по моему опыту это в России уже давно развито. Создается новое ЗАО, формально хозяйственно самостоятельное, а процентов на 70 принадлежащее "папе".

Comment: @avp, я имел в виду это не развито как система. Т.е. нет такого, что устраиваясь на работу в фирму, работник понимает что вершиной его карьерной лестницы будет партнёрство в этой фирме и он может строить свою карьеру исходя из этого. В первую очередь, из-за того что бухгалтерский и налоговый учёт совсем не прозрачный в большенстве случаев.

Answer (score 0):

Лично знаю по крайней мере одного такого человека: Тимофей Прохоров, http://vk.com/timprox

Comment: @Михаил М,

        Only logged in users can see this profile.

так что напишите, что за бизнес у него.

Comment: У нас ещё осталось 3 человека, незарегистрированных во ВК?! :)

Например, вот страничка их компании. 90 сотрудников. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0EHnBhPmFK4J:https://ru-ru.facebook.com/ittop.mobi+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru

Comment: ВК? А что там делать? 

Болтать, вообще неизвестно с кем, неизвестно о чем?